# Webpack angularjs copy angularjs templates but don't include in javascript bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

What I'm trying to do is configure webpack in a way that would copy all the partial html templates that are required in angular 1.x directives etc. into a separate folder (just like the file-loader does for assets referenced from css). I don't want the partial htmls to be included in my javascript bundle but rather have all of them in one folder with hashed names.

I tried configuring the file-loader to do it but when I run webpack in watch mode it also copies the those html in the dist folder again to it appending a new hash and essentially makes an infinite loop as every new html that shows up in that folder is copied, thus a new html appears and again and again. I tried to set an `exclude` matching pattern for that loader but webpack was still running constantly watching over that folder.

Here is the excerpt of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /bundle\/templates/,
        loader: `file-loader?name=bundle/templates/[name]-[hash].[ext]
    ]
}
```

is there a loader that would help me do what I want without resorting to hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer. The problem wasn't the `file-loader` which is configured correctly like this even without the `exclude`. What caused the infinite loop was a dynamic require that created a regex that matched those copied assets too... So by setting a proper context for this dynamic require the problem was resolved.

Comment: Are you able to share your solution? It might be useful for others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In the webpack.config file you can use the same way like this in the loader section. 

     { 
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'views/'
        }
    },
```

And in the plugins section of the webpack.config file

```
 plugins: [ 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
]
```

This will copy all the htmls and will be refered from the index.html